Did the British government or the National Health Service at any point during the 1940s, 1950s or 1960s actively recruit nurses from the Caribbean?
Like many people, I used to believe that the British government invited people from the Caribbean to Britain after the Second World War to help fill a labour shortage. A few years ago, I watched a video on YouTube which informed me that this was untrue. Having done my own research online, I now realise that it is indeed a myth. No such invitation was ever issued by the British government and indeed the arrival of HMT Windrush in June 1948 occasioned considerable alarm within the government and Parliament.
However, there might be a couple of exceptions to this.
Firstly, London Transport did during the 1950s recruit people directly from the Caribbean, although this was apparently done at the request of the government of some Caribbean countries who wanted to encourage the emigration of their unemployed residents.
Secondly, it does appear that from 1949, the NHS did encourage Caribbean women to come to Britain to train as nurses. Simon Webb of the History Debunked YouTube channel says that these women were brought to the UK so that they could train as nurses and go back and work in the Caribbean, although some stayed. However, this article on the Black History Month website says that it was always intended that they would work in Britain:
The myth of the Windrush Generation being invited to rebuild Britain after the war is now so widespread that no article, book, TV programme or online video alleging that some people were indeed invited can be trusted unless it clearly cites a primary source. Even recollections of the nurses themselves would have to be treated with caution as their memories might have been polluted by the Windrush myth.
Does anyone have enough knowledge of this subject to say definitively, citing primary sources, whether or not the British government or Local Health Authorities ever directly recruited women from the Caribbean to come and work as nurses in Britain?

Doesn't Wikipedia (mostly) answer this question? In particular, "The Ministry of Labour was particularly opposed to recruiting labour from the Caribbean, arguing that "previously advertised shortages no longer existed. In labor sectors where shortages could not be denied, the ministry concentrated on demonstrating that colonial citizens would make unsuitable workers"" and "The arrival of West Indian immigrants on the Empire Windrush was not expected or approved of by the British government."


the British government invited people from the Caribbean to Britain after the Second World War to help fill a labour shortage.

As a comment mentions, Wikipedia addresses the reality at this general level. The British Nationality Act of 1948 allowed Carribean subjects to come and work and live as citizens, and they did. If this was explicitly the intent or not would probably depend on which member of Parliament you asked at the time.
The article linked to in the question spells out concrete ways that nurses of Carribean origin were recruited. Although it is unfortunate that the article doesn't cite any sources, the basic facts should not be hard to verify with a bit of digging. In 2006 the NHS published a whole book with extensive documentation entitled, Many Rivers to Cross: Caribbean People in the NHS 1948-69 by Ann Kramer. It's not online except for the Google Books preview, but you can probably find a copy through your local library if you're in the UK.
Another source of interest is a book chapter, "'In England We Did Nursing’: The Experiences of Caribbean and British Nurses in Great Britain and Canada, 1950-70" which can be downloaded from Academia.edu. It quotes interviews with nurses of Carribean origin who were trained as nurses in England but ended up settling in Canada where the need for labor was greater.
Are there general misconceptions? Maybe. But I'm not seeing any clear mis-statement of fact here that can be rightfully debunked as a "myth". The bottom line is that colonial history and postwar policies led thousands of Carribean immigrants to take jobs in the UK health sector during the period in question.

Personally, I would interpret the Act of 1948 to be a clear signal to those in the Caribbean. Not specifically a personal "invitation", but opening the door wide to those knocking on it to come in. If Parliament didn't think people would come that is on them.

@JonCuster No disagreement there, but I think whether it counts as "active recruitment" or not strikes me as open to interpretation.

I would agree, and I suspect a historian would need to see what is available from the debates in Commons. They passed the Act for some reason(s).

The question is well-studied and it seems fairly settled that "policy makers had no intention that nationality law would facilitate an unprecedented non-White migration from the Commonwealth" (source). What's obvious in hindsight isn't always obvious at the time.

Roger that. Vaguely curious that nobody in debate brought up the point (not the 'policy makers' but MPs). But I am more than satisfied.

Thanks for the reply to my question. The Wikipedia article says that the 1948 Act gave residents of the colonies "the right of entry and settlement in the UK", but two sentences later it states that the first ships carrying immigrants from the Caribbean arrived in 1947! The truth is that the 1948 Act did not give residents of the Colonies any settlement rights that they did not already have. HMT Windrush itself arrived before the Act came into force (in 1949). So not only was the Act not intended to give Caribbean people settlement rights, it didn't even have that effect!

@EdwardH Apparently there were two such ships. But it doesn't follow that "the 1948 Act did not give residents of the Colonies any settlement rights that they did not already have'. Where are you getting that part from?

Brian Z, my understanding is that British subjects had always had right of entry. The 1905 Aliens Act was, I believe, the first Act of Parliament that restricted entry to the UK and that seems to have exempted British subjects from immigration controls: https://www5.open.ac.uk/research-projects/making-britain/content/aliens-act#:~:text=The%201905%20Aliens%20Act%20did%20not%20discriminate%20against,had%20discriminated%20against%20seafarers%20from%20the%20Indian%20subcontinent.

@EdwardH Freedom of movement and citizenship are two very different things. I haven't looked for a systematic analysis of what actually changed, but that's what stands out to me.

I know freedom of movement and citizenship are two very different things. That's exactly my point! The 1948 Act was about citizenship and had nothing to do with freedom of movement.

@EdwardH I think I see your point and made a small edit. Clearly citizenship matters to nigrants, even if it's not strictly required just to come and work.

I understand that in the 1950s many people in Britain, perhaps particularly in the Conservative Parliamentary Party were keen in theory on the Commonwealth as they had exaggerated hopes it would make up for the gradual loss of Empire and allow Britain to continue to be a global Great Power. It was not that they wanted or expected mass immigration from other Continents, which had not previously occurred during the British Empire itself, but which modern means of transport made possible.

@JonCuster: illusions during that period were not limited to  the UK. Germany somewhat later invited Turkish workers thinking they'd later leave etc.
